# load an existing pdf in a C# application using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, itext

I need to know how do i load an existing .pdf ;say i have a .pdf in my local machine i added it to the location where i am creating a project i need to load this .pdf in my c# app and then i need to add some changes to it .

I created an empty c# project added an assembly info
In the references i added the following

```
iTextSharp
Microsoft.CSharp
System
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtension
System.XML
System.XML.Ling
```

And a class as PdfClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace contextcopypdf
{
     public class PdfClass
        {
            //function that loads an exisitng pdf
            public void LoadPdf()
            {
               string inputPdf = "sign.pdf";
               string outputPdf = "sign1.pdf";
               Pdfreader = new PdfReader(inputPDF);

            }
        }
 }
```

The IDE Is VS 2010 ultimate

Basically on this pdf i have got digital signature fields.

Thanks

Comment: i also added added the sign.pdf to my project 's working loc still i need to give a full path also i want to do the changes to the existing file loaded

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code there that loads the pdf, change the path accordingly if needed.

```
        var path = @"c:\Templates\Invoice.pdf";

        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);
```

Comment: how do i handle exception with var pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);

Comment: if in case the memory is not initialosed

Answer (score 0):

I see that your requirement is to digitally sign a PDF. Please read my book about digital signatures to make sure you do this correctly: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures/

The examples in the book are in Java, but we've ported most of the examples to C#. You can find these examples here: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/

Browse for tutorial/signatures. Make sure you create CMS or CAdES signatures. The older flavors will be deprecated soon (or are already forbidden in PAdES).

Comment: @user1838130 Start by having a look at the Sign method in [C2_01_SignHelloWorld](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/485/tree/tutorial/signatures/chapter2/C2_01_SignHelloWorld/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.cs), one of the examples Bruno pointed towards.